# Embedding YouTube Channel into website using React and Typescript. Page says 404

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I run the below code the Page runs, The Youtube player inside shows 404. I am wondering if my embedded url is wrong. As you can see below I am first creating a const called YouTubePlayer which loads `https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=${channelID}` as the URL.

```
import React from 'react';
//import MyPostsDashboard from 'src/app/pages/dashboard/components/MyPostsDashboard';

interface YouTubePlayerProps {
  channelID: string;
}
 
const YouTubePlayer: React.FC<YouTubePlayerProps> = ({ channelID }) => {
  const embedUrl = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=${channelID}`;
  return (
  <div>
    <iframe
      id="ytplayer" 
      width="640" height="360"
      src="{embedUrl}"            
    ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};


const MyComponent = () => {
  const channelID = 'UCm9C6bqd05CQOVdOSC6fV2g';
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to My YouTube Channel</h1>
      <YouTubePlayer channelID={channelID} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Have you tested your **embedded url** in the browser, by just simply entering it and visiting it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's no way to get this feature for this style of channel name. See [this tracker link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35174959)

> Yes. It's not possible to embed a YouTube channel that only has a Google+ username.
>
> So while older channels (with regular usernames) will still function, for > example the Ashens channel:
> https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=ashens
>
> It's impossible to generate such a list with a newer channel like
> https://www.youtube.com/c/DutchNerdClub